# Angular5 / Firebase Storage are not working when using third-part libraries to zoom images

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, firebase-storage, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm building an e-commerce using Angular5 and Google Cloud Firestore as Database. In the products page, I want to zoom a photo when the mouse hover the picture. Here's the problem:

As a zoom library, I'm using [angular2-image-zoom](https://github.com/brtnshrdr/angular2-image-zoom). It works fine with images that are inside of my project, but when I pass a external image source (coming from Firebase storage, it doesn't work).

Code example:

`product-page.component.ts`

```
  // This example doesn't work
    <img  
      class="img-responsive"
      [imageZoom]="externalPhoto" // ~>https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/... 
      [src]="externalPhoto" 
      [style.width.px]="width" 
      [style.height.px]="height">

  //This example works fine
  <img 
    class="img-responsive"
    [imageZoom]="logoSrc" // ~>'assets/img/shared/logo.png';
    [src]="logoSrc" 
    [style.width.px]="width" 
    [style.height.px]="height"
  >
```

I already try all kind of DomSanitizer to bypass url, style, secureSrc but none of them worked. Do you guys have some suggestion?

Comment: Does it work without the zoom lib? Ie. you can see an image?

Comment: Found at least one potential bug in the lib you're using: If the image is cached, it doesn't do anything because the load event is never triggered (at least in some browsers). https://github.com/brtnshrdr/angular2-image-zoom/blob/c557576286d39d832f020011adf8445e2adb0ad9/src/image-zoom.directive.ts#L72

Comment: Should trigger the load event callcack manually if this.img.complete

Comment: So does it work if you go to chrome devtools network tab and disable caching?

Comment: @funkizer it works without the lib, yes.  The only alternative I found was using another lib. This lib works fine ~> https://github.com/themyth92/angular2-lightbox with angular5.

About the cache, my browser is already disabled... But, yes, there's a potential bug there.

Comment: Anyway, thank you so much for the effort to read and analyse my question!

Comment: Np. Glad you found an alternative, I'm guessing it was just a buggy lib :)